# Подключение css к cgi серверу на питоне

Tags: python, cgi

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой - не могу указать путь к стилям на простом cgi сервере
Cкриншот самого сервера (1)

Подключение css. По структуре ошибок нет, путь указан правильно, если его поменять, то выдаёт ошибку о том что файла не существует (2)

Но при заходе на страницу стили не подгружаются, а консоль выдаёт такую ошибку (3)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом если указывать путь не к файлу на компьютере, а например указать ссылку на онлайн бутстрап, то работает нормально. Может кто нибудь подсказать, как это исправить?

Comment: Может какую-то 32 битную либу используете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте все тексты с картинок прямо в тело вопроса. Это обеспечит возможность поиска.

Answer (score -1):

Всё, я сам разобрался. Проблема была в том что стили лежали внутри папки cgi-bin (/project/cgi-bin/media). Я вынес стили на один уровень выше (в папку project) и всё заработало.

Comment: Не нужно было `../` писать